# how to fix this? E: Type 'by'

Tags: 14.04

```
jubil@junel:~$ sudo apt-get update

E: Type 'by' is not known on line 4 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: Type 'nano' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/some-ppa.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

> jubil@junel:~$ cat -n /etc/apt/sources.list

```
 1. # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 
 2  # (20160803)]/ trusty main restricted
 3  deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted #Added 
 4  by software-properties
 5  
 6  # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade 
 7  # to newer versions of the distribution.
 8  deb http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted deb-src 
 9  http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe 
10  multiverse #Added by software-properties
11  
12  ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the 
13  ## distribution.
14  deb http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted 
15  deb-src http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main 
16  restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
17  
18  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the 
19  ## Ubuntu team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT 
20  ## receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
21  deb http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe deb 
22  http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
23  
24  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the 
25  ## Ubuntu team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy 
26  ## yourself as to your rights to use the software. Also, please note 
27  ## that software in multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates 
28  ## from the Ubuntu security team.
29  
30  deb http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse deb 
31  http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
32  
33  
34  ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as 
35  ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it 
36  ## includes newer versions of some applications which may provide useful 
37  ## features. Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT 
38  ## receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
39  deb http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main 
40  restricted universe multiverse deb-src 
41  http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted 
42  universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
43  
44  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted 
45  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main 
46  restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties deb 
47  http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe deb 
48  http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
49  
50  ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's 
51  ## 'partner' repository. This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is 
52  ## offered by Canonical and the respective vendors as a service to 
53  ## Ubuntu users.
54  deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner deb-src 
55  http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
56  
57  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party 
58  ## developers who want to ship their latest software.
59  deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main deb-src 
60  http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
61  
62  
63
```

> jubil@junel:~$ cat -n /etc/apt/sources.list.d/some-ppa.list

```
 1.
 2
```

> jubil@junel:~$

```
jubil@junel:~$ sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/some-ppa.list
[sudo] password for jubil: 
jubil@junel:~$ sudo apt-get update
E: Type 'by' is not known on line 4 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
jubil@junel:~$
```

Comment: please run `cat -n /etc/apt/sources.list` and `cat -n /etc/apt/sources.list.d/some-ppa.list` and lets see what the problem is

Comment: I'm sorry because it is my first time to use ubuntu... advance thank you for helping....

Comment: @junel please run those two command from the terminal and add them to your question. Just click on the `edit` button and add the result. Run each separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/some-ppa.list
```

and the problem should be fixed.

You added some crap to that file.

Also you have another crap in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

I suggest creating a default list from scratch. Run

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then go to System Settings -> Software & Updates and check all sources at the first tab.

This will re-create the `sources.list`.